# void playoneround not showing in main

Tags: java

I have 3 classes: tDate, tPlayer and tGame.
tPlayer:

```
private String name;
private int my_lucky_number;
private int total_score;
```

i wrote this method in tPlayer:

```
 public void playOneRound()
{
    int x = 0;
    int n =(int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
     if (my_lucky_number > n*5)
     {
         x = my_lucky_number - n*5;
         total_score = total_score + x;
     }
     if (my_lucky_number < n*5)
         x = n*5-my_lucky_number;
     total_score = total_score + x;

   }
```

and it wont let me use it in my main class.

```
total1 = pp1.playOneRound();
```

it says I need to change playOneRound into an int method. 
can't it be void? or am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: It cannot be void if you want to return a value. Kindly [have a look here](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Methods/Lesson1.htm), maybe it helps to understand this.

Comment: You need to change return type of `playOneRound()` from `void` to `int` if you expect method to return value.

Comment: if you are returning an `int` then change to `public int playOneRound()` if you are not returning anything then use `void`

Comment: I need playoneround to be void. and to use it in my main, it doesnt need to return somthing only to update the total score.

Comment: @Nyrre Then change `total1 = pp1.playOneRound();` to just `pp1.playOneRound();` since this method does not return a value.